# PowerShell Windows Forms: Checkbox and Dropdown to CSV

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a CSV which I import and I want to add two additional fields and export it to a new file.  I want to be able to show a Windows form where the user checks a box to change the `FLAG` field to `Y` (unchecked is `N`) and change the status in a dropdown box if necessary based on the values in `$DropDownArray`.

My current issue is that the export occurs before I've clicked `OK`.  I understand why, I just don't know where to put the export function (`$SAMTemp2`), due to the dynamic number of items that will appear in the form.

Additionally, I don't know how to set the default value of the dropdown to a specific choice in the array based on the `Status` cell in the CSV.

```
$RowPlus=60
$Next=0
[array]$DropDownArray = "FVR","C","O","P"

Import-Csv $SAMTemp4 | ForEach{


#Service Order Description
$objLabel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,$RowPlus)
$objLabel2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(540,20)
$objLabel2.Text = $_.SO+"          "+$_.ProdProj+" ("+$_.SrvcTask+")"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel2)

#Planned/Unplanned Checkbox
$objTypeCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$objTypeCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(558,$RowPlus) 
$objTypeCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
#$objTypeCheckbox.Text = "Planned Task"
$objTypeCheckbox.TabIndex = 4
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTypeCheckbox)

#Status Dropdown Box
$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(610,$RowPlus)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,30)
If($_.Status -eq "Open"){$ST = $Dropdown.Items[3]}
If($_.Status -eq "Closed"){$ST = $Dropdown.Items[2]}
$DropDown.SelectedItem = $ST
$objForm.Controls.Add($DropDown)
    ForEach ($s in $DropDownArray) {
     [void] $DropDown.Items.Add($s)
    }

If($objTypeCheckbox.Checked -eq $true){
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Flag -Value 'Y'
}Else{
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Flag -Value 'N'
}
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name COPFVR -Value $Dropdown.selecteditem

$RowPlus+=30
$Next+=1

$_

} | Export-Csv $SAMTemp2 -NoTypeInformation
#This creates the Ok button and sets the event
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,540)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$empID=$objTextBox1.Text;$sn=$objTextBox2.Text;$gn=$objTextBox3.Text;$email=$objTextBox4.Text;$title=$objDepartmentListbox.SelectedItem;
                     $office=$objOfficeListbox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
$OKButton.TabIndex = 9
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

#This creates the Cancel button and sets the event
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,540)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$CancelButton.TabIndex = 10
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

(In case it isn't obvious, I lifted the initial form from a TechNet question, so there are .Add_ functions still in there I didn't adjust.)
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/e3d80f73-55f6-4a7e-95b5-4e9216ef1847/powershell-windows-forms-checkbox?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: I also tried `If($_.Status -eq "Open"){$DropDown.SelectedItem = $DropDown.Items[3]}
Else{$DropDown.SelectedItem = $Dropdown.Items[2]}` for selecting the default value since it will always be one of those two, but that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: You will need to save the CSV as a variable if you want to be able to manipulate it in memory before exporting. You also need to add events so that your code is executed when things change. Then add the Export command to the add_Click method of the OK button.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I'm not sure what you mean by 'You also need to add events so that your code is executed when things change.'  Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are creating your OK button and displaying the dialog after the excel is exported. And do you really intend to show the dialog for each row in the CSV file?

Comment: It appears you are trying to dynamically add controls based on your CSV content. Best practice here is to have a predefined set of controls and use the data bound to those controls to reflect your CSV content. My suggestion would be to use the DataGridView winforms control. You would create a DataTable from your CSV and bind it to the DataGridView. The user would then be able to change the values within the DataGridView and then simply set up an event handler to export the changed data to the new CSV.

Comment: @atownson Thanks.  I'm reading on the DataGridView now, but I'm not having any luck finding out about adding checkboxes and dropdown lists to it.  Any leads?

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) is the best resource. It'll be a deep dive if this is your first winforms project. Google for some C# code. It's pretty easy to translate that to Powershell. I've written many of these so it's doable.